# Exctracting Parameter Types from Mangled C++ Name

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out the type of the parameters passed to a function. 
I want to do this using the mangled name of the function.

For example the following function has the parameters
`_ZN7MyClass3funEP14AnAwesomeClass`

`MyClass* this, AnAwesomeClass* p1`

I now want to generate a function call to the toString member function of each passed parameter.

E.g.

`_ZN7MyClass7toStringEv`

and

`_ZN14AnAwesomeClass7toStringEv`

It is not very hard to demangle a name. But how do I extract the parameters and remangle them into a new function name?

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: [c++filt Demangle C++ and Java symbols.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/c++filt)

Comment: So, you want to generate the mangled name of a function that isn't used by your program, using the mangled name of a function that is?  Why?

Comment: Because I want to call the toString method on each parameter passed to the function for debugging purposes.

Comment: Then why not just call the toString method without worrying about mangling?  Is there something special you're doing that you're not telling us about?

Comment: because there is not one toString method, there is one method per class and therefore I need to mangle the parameters type into the toString methods name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a few ways:

1. [c++filt](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html)
2. [nm -C](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm)
3. [objdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) -t -C

Answer (score 1):

Several tools have been listed for g++ and other *nix compilers; I add also [`undname` and `dumpbin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx) for VC++.